# Kong Gateway Response Rate-Limiting plugin not working

Tags: rate-limiting, kong, kong-plugin

I was able to configure Kong Gateway Response Rate-Limiting plugin but facing an issue while accessing an API.

Always see the below response When the **Repsonse rate-limiting plugin** is enabled on any API.

{
"message": "An unexpected error occurred"
}

Any suggestions/inputs is of great help.